# margin 0 auto не работает

Tags: html, css

недавно начала изучать верстку, пытаюсь сделать шапку, но не получается выровнять элементы списка

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 51px;
  background-color: #212121;
}

header nav {
  padding: 10px 460px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Главная</a></li>
        <li class="menu_item">
          <a href="#" class="menu_link">Со своим автомобилем</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
          <a href="#" class="menu_link">На автомобиле компании</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
          <a href="#" class="menu_link">Требования</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
          <a href="#" class="menu_link">Контакты</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
          <a href="#" class="menu_link">Оставить заявку</a>


        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Еще  изменить : padding: 10px 460px; -- на что-то более приемлемое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя nav имеет ширину 100%. Чтобы margin: 0 auto; срабатывал, ширина блока должна быть меньше, чем ширина родителя.
То есть если задать ширину nav, например, 70%,всё сработает.